# iOS. Implement incremental param for requests?

Tags: ios, request, auto-increment, increment, post-increment

[Link to API](https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/privateapi)

There is a param "nonce":

> An additional security element must be passed into the post: 
>        nonce - All requests must also include a special nonce POST parameter with incrementing integer. The integer must always be
>   greater than the previous requests nonce value.

Of course I can implement it via integer param and perform `++` operation each time I use it, but what to do if this value is less than it is required and it causes request error? For example if it was reset for example after application reinstall?

Comment: you can either keep this integer variable in key chain, then after reinstall it will not reset, or you can store this variable at your server and as part of server response you can fetch it for further use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly I found a solution:

```
@((int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970])
```

I saw in php they use `microtime()` function. I hope my function will give the same result